# modify my PHP Theme toRemove outofstock from this list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm a developer but I don't have experience in PHP;
We're using woocommerce them for a site, I have a problem in sale box, I want to remove out of stock products from our list (just display available products)
I share the code here

```
$settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
$query_options = array('category_id' => $settings['category_id'], 'posts_per_page' => $settings['posts_per_page'], 'orderby' => 'on_sale', 'post_type' => 'product');
$query_data = \mweb_theme_query::get_custom_query( $query_options );
```

please help me to solve our problem

Comment: Not clear whether that method there actually executes via WP_Query or WC_Product_Query (or something else altogether), but https://stackoverflow.com/q/36205792/1427878 has some hints on what could work.

Comment: I find definition of the  get_custom_query, its return WP_Query Data

Comment: Use meta_query to exclude by stock status 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key'  => '_stock_status', 'value'     => 'outofstock', 'compare'   => 'NOT IN' ))  something like that ?

Comment: Another option is to just hide out of stock products from your catalog go to Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Inventory  -> Outofstock visibility option set to true.

Comment: thanks martin at least I find the mother class and apply _stock_status on it and works after 2 days trying
unfortunately out of mother class the changes in _stock_status not worked